# filter a array in a list that contain a certain value

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, filter

I have list

```
combi_col = [[0,1,2][0,1],[0],[1,2],[0,2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3,1]
```

I want to filter this list to only show a list that only contain 0 in the array

The result should only keep all arrays in the list which contain 0

In addition, the array should not contain only 1 value. It should contain minimum 2 values

The result should look like

```
result = [[0,1,2][0,1],[0,2]]
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: show your minimum reproducible code.

Comment: First, this is NOT a valid lists - you may want to fix the *format*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do in one line via list comprehension:

```
[x for x in combi_col if 0 in x and len(x) >= 2]
#[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1], [0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
combi_col = [[0,1,2],[0,1],[0],[1,2],[0,2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3,1]]
result = []

for entry in combi_col:
    if 0 in entry and len(entry) >= 2:
        result.append(entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use built in filter:

```
filtered = list(filter(lambda list_element: 0 in list_element and len(list_element)>1, combi_col))
```

First parameter is function with which you filter, and second is collection to be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from NiiRexo is correct, but you can do the same in one line using list comprehension:

```
result = [nested_list for nested_list in combi_col if len(nested_list)>1 and (0 in nested_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

list = [[0,1,2],[0,1],[0],[1,2],[0,2],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3,1]]
result = []

for i in list:
if 0 in i and len(i) >= 2:
result.append(i)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).